# Why are functions names not shown under 'Run Microtasks' in chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, debugging

I'm having trouble determining which functions are being called in the chrome inspector.

Under the performance tab, when I reload, it will sometimes show the actual function names being called, like "onEnter, homeController..etc, which is what I'm after.

[image]

However, this only happens very rarely and randomly as far as i can tell. Instead nine times out of ten, I just get the "Run Microtasks" WITHOUT any function names beneath it. (see below). This makes debugging very difficult.

[image]

How do I make sure that it ALWAYS shows the function names when I reload?